# How can I run a VBScript file silently in the background?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, sap-gui

I want to run a VBScript file silently, because it is just a part of a hidden script.

I'm using the VBScript to export automatically documents out of SAP, that is working perfectly, unless showing each step in the SAP GUI.

The VBScript file is started in a PowerShell, where I already tried to hide the process like:

```cs
$vbsPDPPath = "$env:userprofile\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport"  
$vbsPDPName = "SAP-ExportPDP.vbs"
$processNamePDP = $vbsPDPPath + "\" + $vbsPDPName
Start-Process $processNamePDP -WindowStyle Hidden
```

Didn't work out though.

I'm looking for a solution like in VBA, where you can just add:

```vb
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

Still have no idea how to solve it. I thought it would be helpful to let you see the VBS code, there must be the fault.

I noticed that I haven't mentioned to hide the SAP GUI as well as the Excel Application.

```
Dim Number_PDP
Dim testNode
Dim WshShell
Dim profile

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
profile = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

'read XML file

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("MSXML.DomDocument")
xmlDoc.Load profile & "\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport\DIS.xml" 

For Each testNode In xmlDoc.selectNodes("/Reports/Report")

   Number_PDP = testNode.SelectSingleNode("DIS_PDP").Text

               'connect to SAP GUI

If Not IsObject(application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto  = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set application = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(connection) Then
   Set connection = application.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session    = connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session,     "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject application, "on"
End If

SapGuiAuto.Visible = false 
              'not working, thought it is possible to hide SAP

session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 132,31,false
session.findById("wnd[0]/tbar[0]/okcd").text = "/n cv04n"
session.findById("wnd[0]").sendVKey 0
...
              'cutted a couple of rows, just opens a document in Excel with SAP


              'after SAP opens Excel I used this code to save the documents 
set objExcel = getobject(,"Excel.Application")

if err.number<>0 then
    err.clear
end if
              'this part should be hidden as well, not working
objExcel.Visible = false     
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs profile & "\AppData\Roaming\KPIReport\" & Number_PDP
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
objExcel.Quit

Next
```

Comment: Try to use the cscript interpreter in batch mode.`cscript //B $processNamePDP`

Comment: What do you see right now? A CMD screen or a Powersheel screen? How is it kicked off currently?

Comment: @VincentG I tried it, but didn`t work

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I see the SAP-GUI how the script is running an it is kicked off in the powershell script.

Comment: So there must be some code inside the VBS that manipulates the SAP GUI. I guess that's where you need to make the change.

Comment: If you are using COM it probably has a .Visible property. Try setting it to false inside your VBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a workaround in both cases.

For example:

```
. . .
'session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 132,31,false
session.findById("wnd[0]").iconify
. . .
```

and

```
. . .
'objExcel.Visible = false     
objExcel.WindowState = 2
. . .
```

Regards,
ScriptMan

Comment: Works perfectly!!